# Unknown matrix notation.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, notation

I have found this notation of a diagonal matrix in a demonstration:
$$D=[\lambda_i \delta_{ij}]$$
Also, in the same demonstration, this other diagonal matrix is used:
$$A=[a_i \delta_{ij}]$$
And then they say:
$$AD=[a_i \lambda_i \delta_{ij}]$$
Obviously the latter is a multiplication, but could someone explain to me how this works? What those $\delta$s and $\lambda$s represent? How the matrix is formed from those? A link with some info about it? Or at least its name so I can look it up? Also, I think I should mention that my level is a beginner; I only started to learn linear algebra a few weeks ago.

Comment: The $\delta$ is probably the Kronecker Delta function $\delta_{ij}$, which is $1$ if $i=j$ and $0$ otherwise.

Comment: @NigelOvermars Thanks. So, if I understand, the thing in between the brackets is the general form of the $a_{ij}$ element of the matrix? Also, excuse my (possibly) bad English; it is not my native language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$ \delta _{ij} = \begin{cases} 
      1 & i = j \\
      0 & i \ne j
   \end{cases}
$$

Thus the notation for $D$ is shorthand for saying $D$ is a diagonal matrix with entries $\lambda_i$ down the diagonal and similarly, $A$ with diagonal entries $a_i$.

One of the many nice properties about diagonal matrices is that they are closed under multiplication. Furthermore, the multiplication structure is nice and easy, namely, just multiply the corresponding diagonal elements and hence, each diagonal entry is of the form $a_i \lambda_i$

Comment: So, if I understood correctly, you specify a matrix in this notation by specifying the general formula for the $a_{ij}$ element? I could, for example, say that $f_{ij}=$ (1, if i < j, and 0 otherwise), and $D=[f_{ij}]$ would mean a matrix with 1s above the diagonal and 0s everywhere else?

Comment: Precisely. I would personally prefer if your book wrote (at least at some point) $[a_{ij}]_{1\le i \le m, 1 \le j \le n}$ for example.

Comment: I guess you are referring to the dimensions of the matrix. It did mention at the beginning that $A$ and $D$ are two square matrices with $n$ rows and columns by saying that $A, D \in M_n(K)$, if that is what you are saying. I omitted that; sorry :)

Comment: No, it was clear what you meant in this context. I am saying I hope that at some point, your book introduced that notation to make it clear it's defining a matrix.

Comment: By the way, while we are at it, what does that $K$ from $M_n(K)$ stand for? I believe it is the set (if that is the proper term; I learned all this in Romanian) from where the elements belong? If so, why is it not $C$ or $R$?

Comment: It is a general field. Examples of fields include $\mathbf{C}$, $\mathbf{R}$, and $\mathbf{Q}$.

Answer (score 1):

It's the [Kronecker delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta), which is defined as $\delta_{ij} = 1 \text{ if i = j, and } 0 \text{ otherwise}$.

So the notation

$$D=[\lambda_i \delta_{ij}]$$

is just a concise way to let the reader know that you will be referring to the diagonal element in the $i$th row by $\lambda_i$.

(Exactly the same situation with $A$).

Comment: And the formula between the brackets for $AD$ is just a consequence of matrix multiplication, right?

Comment: @DJakarta: Exactly.

Comment: Yes, multiplication of two diagonal matrices is easy.